# БД или удаленный сервер?

Tags: android, база-данных, архитектура, мобильная-разработка

Хочу написать свой песенник, который будет содержать очень большой объем текстовый информации.

Не могли бы вы подсказать как лучше это сделать, чтобы не нагружать приложение объемом больше, чем 4-6 мб, есть ли какие то варианты?
Возможно ли подрузка бд с какого-либо сервера при первом запуске приложения?

Comment: А влияет ли такая база на размер исходного апк?

Comment: Приложение под Android?

Comment: Да, использую Android Studio

Comment: В таком случае лучше использовать SQLite с которой по умолчанию работает Android, в процессе можно подгрузить файлы с БД сервера при запуске приложения и локально сохранить во внутреннюю БД при желании пользователя. Насколько вырастит апк не знаю, думаю где-то в районе 1 МБ,

Comment: А какие методы нужно использовать для подгрузки файлов с БД с сервера? Есть примеры какие-нибудь? Гуглил, мало чего нашел

Comment: С самим android я не работал(в след. раз. указывайте в тегах android), но как я понимаю можно использовать просто post запрос к серверу и получить все нужные данные. Поищите по "android post запрос" для получения данных с сервера. Вот только сервер надо будет еще сделать на чем-то, который эти данные отдаст.

Answer (score 4):

При принятии такого решения всегда нужно учитывать несколько противоположных факторов:

- Если вы принимаете решение включить базу в приложение, то насколько
  большим будет размер приложения? Как вы будете обновлять базу?
  Обновлением приложения или с удаленного сервера?
- Если вы принимаете решение пользоваться удаленным сервисом, то
  оправдывает ли приложение использование интернета? Как скачать
  первоначальную базу, если она достаточно большая? Что если сервер временно недоступен или у пользователя отключен интернет? И не забьете ли вы через некоторое время на поддержку и не превратится ли приложение в тыкву?

Лично я бы хотел, чтобы подобное приложение не требовало обязательного соединения с интернетом, поэтому могу предложить такой вариант:

- Положить в apk некую первичную версию базы, насколько позволит размер. Поскольку это текстовая информация, она легко жмется, а при первом запуске ее можно распаковать в локальную БД.
- Обновление базы проходит в фоне с помощью удаленного сервиса,
  например, при каждом запуске. Важно, чтобы это не напрягало
  пользователя сообщениями вроде "не удалось подключиться к сервису". Пользователь может не включать интернет, или ваш сервис умрет. Это обеспечит полезность приложения сразу после установки и избавит пользователя от рисков остаться без работающего приложения.

Comment: Мне тоже нравится больше второй, вами предложенный вариант. Не могли бы вы рассказать или показать пример кода, как должно быть устроено обновление бд через удаленный сервис?

Comment: @Кирилл слишком много вариантов: начиная от платформы и закканчивая конкретным способом. А что тут вообще сложного? Отправляете запрос, получаете данные, десериализуете их в какие-то "сущности", сохраняете в БД.

Comment: Мне бы попроще как-нибудь надо это реализовать, понять, как это должно работать.